# .htaccess redirect all tld's to another and force https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, redirect

Hello i try to redirect all my top level domains to another one and this is already working but i also want to force https. With the following code it is working fine for all top level domains such as '.de', '.net' and so on.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

My problem is i also want to force https for my main tld => '.com'

Well, and here we are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond (http://) !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

For my bad, this is not working. I get an 'Too many redirects' error. My question is now is it the code/redirection or is there something else wrong maybe with the server configuration of my provider? I noticed the 'Too many redirects' error in any way i tried till now for redirect from 'http://' to 'https://' and i tried so many different ways... .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Adds an "or" condition so that it redirects if there's no HTTPS OR if the domain is different.

The `(http://)` isn't a variable, it's a literal "http://", which will obviously never match `^(www\.)?domain\.com$`, which is why that condition is always true.

Since you're using cloudflare, which internally routes requests (that are not HTTPS), you can't use the `%{HTTPS}` variable, you need to look at the forwarding protocol:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: i tested it but i get the error 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'. Is it possible that something is wrong with the settings of my provider (apache). I also want to mention that i use Cloudflare but this is not a point where the problems could come from, or i am wrong? (Note: i always clear my cache and so on, before i test this, so it can not be a problem caused by my browser)

Comment: @user3714751 yes, using cloudflare or aws makes a difference, because the browser talks SSL to cloudflare, but cloudflare does't talk SSL to your server. See the edit above

Comment: I also tested your edit above but i get the same error 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'. I have set Cloudflare to use SSL-Certificate with their setting: flexible. That means that also if i do not have an own ssl-certificate on my server they give me one so i do not need to buy a ssl-certificate which is pretty good because the money i can spend in Cloudflare who protect my site and give me also some other advantages. So maybe this also changes the situation?

Comment: @user3714751 Apparently cloudflare wants you to use `%{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'` instead:  https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-HTTPS-traffic-with-Flexible-SSL-and-Apache-

Comment: Thank you very much for your good help. Yes it seems so i just tried to get this working over my httaccess i didn't search on cloudflare for a solution. Thank you again for the hint, i think i will get this working now. I will mark your answer as solution.